# How to include variable values in histogram titles in R - using by()

Tags: r, title, histogram

I want to produce histograms using by(), how can I access the values of the factors, to include in histogram headings, for example...

```
a <- runif(500, 0, 10)
b <- LETTERS[1:5]
c <- c("Condition1", "Condition2")

x <- data.frame("Variable1" = b, "Variable2"= c, "Value"=a)
head(x)
by(x$Value, x$Variable2, hist)
```

or using two variables

```
by(x$Value, list(x$Variable2, x$Variable1), hist)
```

Is there a way of passing the variable value (eg Condition1) to the title of the histogram using the options within `hist()`, eg putting `function(x) hist(x, main=...)` into `by()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the split up dataframe rather than just the Values. Then you will have more to work with:

```
by(x, x$Variable2, function(x) hist(x$Value, main=unique(x$Variable2) ) )
```

Produced two plots labled `Condition1`, `Condition2`

Comment: Thanks. For the second part, using 2 factors in by(), I can use `paste(unique(x$Variable1), unique(x$Variable2), sep=", ")` in the `main=""` argument.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. When the function is evaluating the first subset, there will only be one value of Variable1, and likewise when it is evaluating the second subset.

Comment: @DWin, that's really cool! I didn't think of splitting up the `data.frame` itself and working from there. CCID's comment makes sense in the context of the full question (where they asked about splitting by two variables) which will result (in this example) in splitting "x" into 10 `data.frame`s.

Comment: @CCID: I think I get your point (belatedly). You were talking about the more general situation of an N x M cross, and yes, your approach should work for that. Apparently I just missed the two factor part in my eagerness to demonstrate the whole dataframe split approach.

Comment: Yes, it was just getting the two variables into the title. Thanks for the answers, @mrdwab as well.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really answer your question, since you're specifying the use of `by()`, but I usually use `split()` and `lapply()` for these types of problems. My approach is usually along the lines of:

```
temp <- split(x$Value, list(x$Variable2, x$Variable1))
lapply(names(temp), function(x) hist(temp[[x]], main = x, xlab = "Value"))
```

Comment: It's interesting that you have not been using the `lapply(split(.), fun)`-approach on whole dataframes. That's how I learned it and _thought_ was the raison d'être of 'split'.

Comment: @DWin, I definitely see the wisdom in your approach! I honestly don't any real programming background, and I've just been informally teaching myself R out of curiosity and because I've found programming to be somewhat... um... *calming*. And so far, I've found that Stack Overflow is a pretty good learning ground.

Comment: You are certainly a fast learner. I think SO is better than r-help for self instruction because of the possibility of editing, but r-help and r-devel mailing lists still has participation of more of R-Core, so they're really the place to take the hard questions.